# How can I make ffmpeg output proper SDP data for a data stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, avcodec

I have a program based on the FFMPEG libraries, to add KLV data to a video stream. When I try to sent the output to an RTSP server (rtsp-simple-server), I get a 400 response.

The apparent reason is that the SDP data for the KLV stream is missing the rtpmap.

I would like to add the missing data either by setting the proper parameters in the contexts, or by specifying the data explicitly.

This is the ANNOUNCE captured with Wireshark

```
ANNOUNCE rtsp://0.0.0.0:8554/test RTSP/1.0
Content-Type: application/sdp
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: Lavf58.29.100
Content-Length: 270

v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 58.29.100
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:10000
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1
a=control:streamid=0
m=application 0 RTP/AVP 97
b=AS:90
a=control:streamid=1
```

Code fragment for initializing the data stream:

```
AVStream* data_track = avformat_new_stream(muxer, nullptr);

if (data_track == nullptr) {
    LOG_ERROR << "failed to open data output stream";
    return nullptr;
}

muxer->oformat->video_codec = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;

AVCodec *klvEncoder = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_SMPTE_KLV);

if (klvEncoder == nullptr) {
    klvEncoder = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_BIN_DATA);
}

if (klvEncoder == nullptr) {
    klvEncoder = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_TEXT);
}

if (klvEncoder != nullptr) {
    klvEncoderContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);

    avcodec_parameters_from_context(data_track->codecpar, encoderContext);
} else {
    avcodec_parameters_copy(data_track->codecpar, pVideoStream->codecpar);
}

data_track->codecpar->codec_tag =  KLV_ID_TAG;
data_track->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_DATA;
data_track->codecpar->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_SMPTE_KLV;
data_track->codecpar->bit_rate = 90000;
data_track->codecpar->format =  AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8;
data_track->stream_identifier = KLV_ID_TAG;
data_track->id = 0x101;
data_track->time_base = video_track->time_base;
data_track->avg_frame_rate = video_track->time_base;
```